# Explicitly broadcasting a scalar

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

Is it possible to explicitly broadcast a scalar to fit an array somehow similar to

```
s[..., np.newaxis]
```

(So I want to add a dimension to `s`, *even if it is only a scalar yet*)

I am currently vectorizing a lot of functions, such that they work for a single datapoint or multiple at once. E.g. this function that either returns a single random normalized vector, or multiple at once:

```
import numpy as np
def randomu(N, M=None):
    """Returns one or M random normalized vectors of R^N."""
    v = np.random.normal(size=N if M is None else (M, N))
    return v / (np.linalg.norm(v) if M is None else np.linalg.norm(v, axis=-1)[:, np.newaxis])
```

One can see that this function is basically the single vector version and the multiple vectors version stitched together with two ternary condtionals. But if it would be possible to broadcast an additional axis to `np.linalg.norm(v, axis=-1)`, no matter if it is a scalar or a vector, then a lot of my functions could be vectorized a lot cleaner.

To be precise: I want the function above to return an `N`-array for arguments `N, None` and to return a `M,N`-array for arguments `N, M` where `M` is some positive integer. (There is one dimension difference between `M=None`and `M=1`)

This would give this explanatory function a similar signature as most numpy functions as `np.zeros`, `np.random.normal`, .... Probably nearly all numpy functions that take an integer or tuple as shape argument.

Comment: Scalars can be converted to 0 dimensional arrays: `np.array(0).ndim` -> `0`

Comment: @MechanicPig that was exactly what I was searching for. I didn't know that's possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebig3000, there is also the `keepdims` keyword argument; I believe you can write `return v / np.linalg.norm(v, axis=-1, keepdims=True)` for the final line to avoid the explicit reintroducing the size 1 dimension for broadcasting, and it'll handle the 1 axis array as well

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs that is, for this example, even better. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear which `scalar` you are worried about.  Your `v` shape is either `(N,)` or `(N,M)`.  The only 'scalar' I see is the result of the `norm`, and that's a `numpy.float64`.  It takes the `[...,None]` indexing:

```
In [275]: np.linalg.norm(np.ones((3)), axis=-1)
Out[275]: 1.7320508075688772
In [276]: np.linalg.norm(np.ones((3)), axis=-1)[...,None]
Out[276]: array([1.73205081])
```

`norm`, like many "reduction" functions, takes a `keepdims` parameter, which ends up doing the same thing:

```
In [277]: np.linalg.norm(np.ones((3)), axis=-1, keepdims=True)
Out[277]: array([1.73205081])
```

For a two array:

```
In [278]: np.linalg.norm(np.ones((3,2)), axis=-1)
Out[278]: array([1.41421356, 1.41421356, 1.41421356])    
In [279]: np.linalg.norm(np.ones((3,2)), axis=-1)[...,None]
Out[279]: 
array([[1.41421356],
       [1.41421356],
       [1.41421356]])    
In [280]: np.linalg.norm(np.ones((3,2)), axis=-1, keepdims=True)
Out[280]: 
array([[1.41421356],
       [1.41421356],
       [1.41421356]])
```

These work with a `v/...`, since (3,) and (1,) broadcast, as do (3,2) and (3,1).

```
def randomu(N, M=None):
    """Returns one or M random normalized vectors of R^N."""
    v = np.random.normal(size=N if M is None else (M, N))
    return v / np.linalg.norm(v, axis=-1, keepdims=True)

In [284]: randomu(3)
Out[284]: array([-0.92136225, -0.35801172,  0.15139094])

In [285]: randomu(3,1)
Out[285]: array([[-0.2261399 ,  0.16987621, -0.95916777]])

In [286]: randomu(3,2)
Out[286]: 
array([[-0.73506825,  0.63749884, -0.23080272],
       [ 0.34294788,  0.93787639, -0.05267469]])
```